# How do I get the file location from this save method

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a method that takes an image's URL and attempts to save it in memory. I need to retrieve this saved file later, and want to do so by getting its file path. How do I get the file name from this save method?

```
       InputStream input;
        try {
            URL url = new URL (strURL);
            input = url.openStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/"+pos+".png");
            try {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            finally {
                output.close();
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
```

I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Looks like you're writing to "/sdcard/"+pos+".png" ....no?

Comment: Indeed. So the file name is pos + ".png". And you are the only one who knows the value of pos. The file path would be "/sdcard/" + pos + ".png".

Comment: Y'all were spot on. Thank you.